# Android imgButton event

Tags: android, scroll, onclick, onclicklistener, mouseclick-event

I use 2 controller for my project, when i click imgButton with air mouse my ListScroll is well but if i click dpad ok button scroll not working optimize. What can i do for this case. My code here;

```
imgNextPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pDialogList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            scrollDown();
            prevCount = 0;

        }
    });
```

scrollDown method is here

```
private void scrollDown() {

    grd.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
    grd.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(adp.getCount(), 0, 1000);
    grd.setSelection(newAdapter - oldAdapter);
    grd.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == 0) {
                grd.requestFocusFromTouch();
                grd.setSelection(newAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens to the list in the second case, exactly?

Comment: scroll is run 4-5 times so this is not properly